# Erlang: How to assertMatch IoDevice value?

Tags: erlang

I am trying to write a test for opening a file. File open returns a value of the form:

```erlang
{ok, IoDevice} | {error, Reason}
```

IoDevice example value is: `<0.941.0>`

I have tried the following so far (some of them I didn't believe they would succeed anyway...):

```
?assertMatch([], theIoDevice).
?assertMatch("[]", theIoDevice).
?assertMatch(<>, theIoDevice). % Won't compile
```

and several more tests, but I fail.

What is the way to match the IoDevice pattern?

Is there possibility to match to Regular Expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file:open/2` always returns a `tuple` with two elements:

1. The atom `ok` and the pid of a process handling the file (a genserver).

or:

2. The atom `error` and a string.  But because a string is a shortcut for creating a list, the tuple really contains the atom `error` and a list.

But `theIoDevice` is an atom that will never match an empty list, `[]`, or the two element list, `"[]"`, which is a shortcut for creating the list `[91,93]`.

You can't know the pid of the process that is handling a file ahead of time, so you can't try to match a specific pid, but you could assert that you got `{ok, _}` back from `file:open/2`.  If you wanted to get more granular, you could check the second element with `is_pid/1`:

```
?assert(is_pid(File)).
```

You can manually create a pid like this:

```
list_to_pid("<0.4.1>") -> pid()
```